# How to achieve the same result from comma and bracket notation in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

> The general format is arr_2d[row][col] or arr_2d[row,col]. recommended
>   is comma notation for clarity

consider I have a numpy array

```
arr_2d = np.arange(0,9).reshape((3,3))

arr_2d[:,0] # in row form but the data will be of the column.
>> array([0, 3, 6])
```

**so how can i access the first column using bracket notation.**

Comment: You can first transpose the numpy array and then call `arr_2d.T[0]`.

Comment: I would be useful if you gave a more concrete example of the output you want. That is, given your input array of `0..9` with shape `3,3` what is the output you want. eg. `[0,3,6]` as a 2D array with shape `3,1` (as opposed to a 1D array with shape `3`).

Comment: You can't.  That equivalence only applies with scalar indexes, not with slices.

Comment: The answers to your previous question are adequate

Comment: What's the source of this quote?  For a full discussion of indexing see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: This isn't just a matter of notation.  The evaluation steps are different.  One uses one `__getitem__` call and a tuple argument.  The other is two calls, and scalar arguments.